# Why does Python index error for big data?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, index-error

I have a python code  that works very well for example for csv constaining 3x50 floats, and also smaller datas. However, when I try it with 3x3360 csv data I get an "indexerror". I think Jupyter Notebook has a data limit, since it is an online platform. But Spyder does not as far as I know. But Spyder does the same.
What could be the reason for this?
It works for multiple data sizes, but not beyond a limit.

I tried in Jupyter Notebook and Spyider, but it gave an error. Indexing the code is certainly good, yet it did not fix it.
(Maybe I should just run it in Anaconda Prompt or terminal manually or what could I do?)
Thanks the answers

Comment: Please show the complete traceback that is returned

Comment: How could *we possibly tell you what your error is* without seeing a [mcve]? The only thing we can say is *you are getting an index error because you are trying to index some sequence with an index that is out of range*. This almost certainly has nothing to do with running this in a Jupyter Notebook or Spyder (neither have "data limit"). Please see [ask]. Again, you *must* provide a [mcve]